# JQuery - "highlight" effect help

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Looking at the "highlight" JQuery effect:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

You can change the background color of any DIV to fade in/out

However, the example is to "highlight" on a "click" event

```
$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

How can I programatically call the highlight method as though it was a function within my code (instead of activate on a 'click' event)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$("div").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

As pointed by JorenB this will highlight all the div's in your page.

If you only want to highlight one div like:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

You should do:

```
$("div#myDiv").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

If you want to highlight all div's with a specific classe you cand do:

```
<div id="myDiv1" class="myClass"></div>
<div id="myDiv2" class="myClass"></div>

$("div.myClass").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

For more information on selectors see [JQuery Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Comment: Which will highlight all divs in your page ;-) To clarify: give the div an id and use `$("div#{yourid}")` to jQuery it.

Comment: just a question, because I'm not 100% sure, but wouldn't 'div#myDiv' actually be slower than just '#myDiv'?

Answer (score 4):

it would simply be

```
$([your selector]).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve that by triggering the click event, if you have that in your click handler anyway:

```
$('div').click();
```

or:

```
$('div').trigger('click');
```